# Reading List of webpages in R and saving the output in csv

Tags: html, r, csv, parsing

I have a list of 40,000 web-pages address in a csv file. I want to read these pages in a new csv file such that each cell in the csv is the content of the associated web page. 
I am able to read (parse) a single webpage using the following code

```
library(XML)

# Read and parse HTML file
doc.html = htmlTreeParse('',useInternal = TRUE)

# Extract all the paragraphs (HTML tag is p, starting at
# the root of the document). Unlist flattens the list to
# create a character vector.
doc.text = unlist(xpathApply(doc.html, '//p', xmlValue))

# Replace all \n by spaces
doc.text = gsub('\\n', ' ', doc.text)

# Join all the elements of the character vector into a single
# character string, separated by spaces
doc.text = paste(doc.text, collapse = ' ')
```

is it possible to use the csv having the web pages address as input and get a new file with all the content as mentioned above?

Comment: Folks who help you with code shld be aware they are helping someone who is most likely violating the ToS of many sites (here's Mashable's): _"You may not use spiders, robots, data mining techniques or other automated devices or programs to catalogue, download or otherwise reproduce, store or distribute content available on the Service."_

Comment: It was just an example I was giving. I am not collecting the data from mashable.

Comment: so you're certifying that you've either verified that you are in compliance with the ToS of the sites represented by the 40,000 URLs OR have contacted each of them that have restrictions and obtained permission?

Comment: I'm using a public data available on UCI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try the following code. It should work work your purposes, but its untested as I do not know the websites that you are meaning to look at:

```
library(XML)
library(rvest)


df <- read.csv("Webpage_urls.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)

webpage_parser <- function(x){
x <- read_html(x)

  doc.html = htmlTreeParse(x, useInternal = TRUE)
  # Extract all the paragraphs (HTML tag is p, starting at
  # the root of the document). Unlist flattens the list to
  # create a character vector.
  doc.text = unlist(xpathApply(doc.html, '//p', xmlValue))

  # Replace all \n by spaces
  doc.text = gsub('\\n', ' ', doc.text)
  # Join all the elements of the character vector into a single
  # character string, separated by spaces
  doc.text = paste(doc.text, collapse = ' ')
}

all_webpages <- lapply(df, function(x) webpage_parser(x))

Pages <- do.call(rbind, all_webpages)

Parsed_pages <- cbind(df, Pages)

write.csv(Parsed_pages, "All_parsed_pages.csv", row.names = F)
```

If we want to same time, we can use the `doParallel` library in R, this will set up multiple clusters (instances of R) and should help speed up your process.

```
library(doParallel)
# split your webpage list into n vectors and create a list called Split_df

Split_df <- list(df1, df2, df3,..., dfn)

# Here I initiate my cluster
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
registerDoParallel(cl)

Parsed_pages  <- foreach(i = 1:length(Split_df), .combine = rbind) %dopar%
{
  library(rvest)
  library(XML)
  all_webpages <- lapply(Split_df[[i]], function(x) webpage_parser(x))

  Pages <- do.call(rbind, all_webpages)

  Parsed_pages <- cbind(Split_df[[i]], Pages)

  Parsed_pages
}
stopCluster(cl)

write.csv(Parsed_pages, "All_parsed_pages.csv", row.names = F)
```

Comment: It is taking a lot of time.. More than 2 hrs.. Is it possible to make it faster?

Comment: You could try and split your website list into equal number of smaller groups and then use `library(doParallel)` toutilize all of your cores to perform the process

Comment: I am new to R.. I can do the splitting of data but can you tell me more about the core?

Comment: Go read up on the `doParallel` library here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf

Comment: `Error in { : 
  task 6 failed - "no applicable method for 'xmlNamespaceDefinitions' applied to an object of class "NULL""` this is the error i am getting when I used the new code...

Comment: @karankothari, it possibly has to do with the websites you are trying to read in. I have added code to use `rvest` as well, I tested the code this morning and it works as it should when I scraped some wikipedia pages.